Is 'sfc /scannow' really needed after 'Dism /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth'?
I've been trying to delve deeper into how Dism /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and sfc /scannow works and came to a conclusion that, in terms of the final result, /RestoreHealth completely covers and does much more than sfc /scannow does.
As far as I understand, system files inside %WinDir% are just hard links to files inside %WinDir%\WinSxS (or the other way around, for hard links it doesn't matter). E.g.:
C:\Windows\System32>fsutil hardlink list advapi32.dll
\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-advapi32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.4597_none_57f0a5343bc8bfc7\advapi32.dll
\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll

And now there is a "cache directory" %WinDir%\WinSxS\Backup and files within it are not hard links but real copies of system files. E.g.:
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Backup>fsutil hardlink list amd64_microsoft-windows-advapi32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.4597_none_57f0a5343bc8bfc7_advapi32.dll_9512793c
\Windows\WinSxS\Backup\amd64_microsoft-windows-advapi32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.4597_none_57f0a5343bc8bfc7_advapi32.dll_9512793c

Some sources (1, 2) say that sfc /scannow actually uses %WinDir%\WinSxS\Backup to restore missing or corrupted system files which makes sense. But remember that the files which sfc /scannow restores, the system files in %WinDir%, are hard links to %WinDir%\WinSxS, the Component Store. And so if Dism /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth fixes the Component Store it should automagically fix related system files in %WinDir% because of hard links. And I presume it additionally fixes the file copies in %WinDir%\WinSxS\Backup.
So what's the point in running sfc /scannow after Dism /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth like Microsoft suggests?

The two commands are very different and do two entirely different functions

Please clarify.

Not only that, in guide somewhere on MS you will find a notification, that they should be executed 2-3 times, also advice was to run DISM then SFC, one after another make them "do the job". Depending on error, if your "restore" folders are corrupt, then those commands "locally" wont do any fixing, i personally use /Online part since there is no way to verify state of local backup.

This still doesn’t answer my question. And “/Online” isn’t about getting backup from Internet - it’s about servicing “live” OS image, i.e. the one from which you are running DISM. As opposed to “offline” - servicing other, “offline” image. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-global-options-for-command-line-syntax?view=windows-11

@Lcferrum - We are tracking that is the case.
